# Powershell - Merge two Note Property

Tags: powershell

How can I merge two Note Property together in powershell?

The following query returns a list of instances but I want to merge the Note Properties as shown below.

```
$((Get-Counter '\Process(Chrome*)\ID Process' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | % {[regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName=$_.InstanceName;InstanceId=$a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value}})
```

Output of the query is:

```
InstanceName                                                InstanceId
------------                                                ----------
Chrome                                                      #2
Chrome                                                      #1
Chrome
```

But I want the output to be something like this..

```
InstanceName
------------ 
Chrome#2
Chrome#1
Chrome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the expression value of your first property to:

```
@{InstanceName="$($_.InstanceName)$($a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value)"}})
```

In full:

```
(Get-Counter '\Process(Chrome*)\ID Process' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | % {[regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName="$($_.InstanceName)$($a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value)"}}
```